# repeat sound during animation play in power point

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I add a sound to an animation.[image]

I want this song be playing during the animation.
[image]

but the sound only plays once and doesn't repeat again.
how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The options you see in the "Timing" tab affect to the animation, not to the sound added to the animation in the "Effect" panel. That's why you don't get repetition.

I would add the sound you want as a song, you can configure an audio to play across the slides while looping until stopped:

[image: Cpture]

*(capture is from Office 2016)*

Comment: want the sound only for one slide not for all of them.

Comment: I found the answer. I use the timing tab of the sound itself ans set it to repeat until click